# Know if a Windows Phone 8 app is running on Windows 10 for phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-10-mobile

Is there any way to know if a Windows Phone 8 app is running on Windows 10 for phone?

I'am registering a ScheduledActionService but is crashing when the app is running on Win10.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rudy Huyn has a blog post which has a helper method for detecting if your app is running on Windows 10 using reflection.

```
using System.Reflection;
using Windows.ApplicationModel;

namespace Huyn.Utils
{
    public class Windows10Helper
    {
        private static bool? _isWindows10;
        public static bool IsWindows10()
        {
            if (!_isWindows10.HasValue)
            {
                _isWindows10 = Package.Current.GetType()
                     .GetRuntimeProperty("Status") != null;
            }
            return _isWindows10.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Just as a note, this only actually works to detect because of the Status property being new to Windows 10. Assuming Microsoft won't be updating the Windows 8.1 to support this new property, this should work perfectly for your scenario.

[Source](http://www.rudyhuyn.com/blog/2015/11/25/how-to-detect-that-your-8-1-app-runs-on-windows-10/)